# Prevent QML window from appearing before all the QML content is available

Tags: python, qml, pyside6

How do I prevent my QML window from being shown until all the QML content is available?

In my example below an empty window is shown after `QQmlApplicationEngine` is created, but the QML content doesn't appear until `app.exec_()` is called. The effect is exaggerated with the `time.sleep(1)` in my example code. The window is white, and then a second later it shows the red background.

What do I need to do so that all QML content is shown when the window appears? Or rather, how do I prevent the window from being shown until all the QML content is ready?

I am running on Windows.

**QML**

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

ApplicationWindow {
    color: "red"
    visible: true
}
```

**Code**

```
import time
from PySide6 import QtQml, QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine("app_window.qml")

# This sleep exaggerates the issue so that you can easily observe
# that an empty window is shown by this point without QML content.
# Without the sleep the empty window looks like a white "flash"
# before the QML content is shown. I want to get rid of this "flash",
# so I don't want the empty window to ever be visible!
time.sleep(1)

app.exec_()
```

Here is a slow-mo recording of what I am seeing, at 1/8 speed playback, with no `time.sleep()`. Note how the window is white when initially shown, and then it changes to red (well, my phone made it orange). I want the window to be red from the first instant that it is visible.

[image: QML window appears, first shown as white and then changes to red.]

Comment: If you remove the time.sleep you see?

Comment: That all the elements are loaded is misleading, for example let's say you have a very heavy image that takes time to download then: is the window fully loaded when the other items are loaded except the image or do you also have to wait for the loading of the image? On the other hand in a GUI don't use time.sleep, if you want to delay then use QTimer.

Comment: The time.sleep() is to exaggerate the problem I am having so that it is easily observed. Without the time.sleep() the empty window is briefly visible before the QML content shows. It looks like a "flash" before the content loads. I don't want an empty window to be shown ever!

Comment: It's odd that you would need to do anything special here. Maybe try delaying setting the `visible` flag to true until you receive the `Component.onCompleted` signal?

Comment: Also, it's odd to see `QtWidgets.QApplication` used in a QML app. The docs suggest using QGuiApplication for QML since you don't need to bring in widgets code.

Comment: @M.Dudley If I remove the time.sleep I don't see what you indicate (I use linux).

Comment: @JarMan -- Thanks. I had tried putting `Component.onCompleted: visible = true` in the QML instead of `visible: true` but it did not make a difference. Also I am a QML noob doing my best with the Qt docs... they don't make is clear what "application" class is appropriate for different situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Widgets** and **QML** are two distinct beasts in the land of Qt.

Normally, you should never mix the two in one project. Read more about the difference and concepts elsewhere.

[QApplication Class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html) is the way to instantiate a Qt Widgets application. Citing the docs:

> QApplication specializes QGuiApplication with some functionality needed for QWidget-based applications. It handles widget specific initialization, finalization.

For QML applications, you go with a bare [QGuiApplication](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html) and a [QQmlEngine](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html) instances. It's important to realize that Qt app manages its lifecycle and event loop, while Qml engine is just like a yet another scripting engine on top of the app's event loop.

There are many moving parts in Qt ecosystem.  I summarized my findings in one big XMind diagram in my [Telegram blog](https://t.me/ratijas_life/56). Check it out rendered.

[image: Qt App]

Comment: Really helpful, I appreciate the info! I still get the "white flash" even when I use `QGuiApplication`.

Comment: @M.Dudley I'm not denying that it *might be* a Qt problem. But have you tried to run some official examples which are known to work well? Analyzing existing source code might give you the insight you need.

Comment: On your advice I tried both the QML and Widget gallery examples for PySide 6.0.2. I see the issue in both. I guess it must be a Qt problem... disappointing! Flaws like this degrade the perceived quality of my app.

Comment: @M.Dudley Qt 6 is pretty much in a beta state so far, and many built-in Qt modules are not ported yet. I'd wait for 6.1 or even 6.2 before dealing with it. In the meantime, Qt5 is going to stick around for a while.

Comment: Oh wait, I assumed PySide6 is for Qt6 only. I had no idea it's for 5.12+. Anyway, I've been using Python with Qt widgets (not QML) through [PyQt5](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/) pretty much without problems.